# IOS 14 (iPhone12) USB tethering

Tags: networking, usb, tethering

I have been trying to use hotspot from ios 14 to ubuntu 16.04.
But currently i am facing issues with both wifi and usb hotspots.

1. With Wifi:
   Unable to connect. Repeatedly asking for password like the password entered is wrong.
   Done with apple support diagnostics and multiple times password reset and even network reset. Still issue persists.
2. With USB:
   Wired connection is showing got connected to Ethernet. But no data flow, no websites are loading.

I am using an HP da0077tx laptop with dual boot win10 and ububntu 16.04 LTS.
Both the methods worked fine with win10 on the same system.
But issues are not fixed with Ubuntu.

Apple support asked to get support from the linux community.

Please help!!!!

Comment: It looks like you have some wrong netework settings in Ubuntu, but it is impossible to tell.

Comment: Anyway to diagnose?? @Pilot6

Comment: Have you tried Bluetooth?  Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 4):

This is [a known issue within ipheth](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/1038) that has plagued a couple of projects ever since the iPhone 12 was released. The solution appears to be reducing the MTU value from 1516 to 1514 in the `ipheth.c` source file, but this breaks ipheth for other iOS devices that are *not* the iPhone 12. More than this, editing driver source files and isn't something that "anyone" is going to do.

From what has been seen in the field so far:

1. WiFi tethering with an iPhone 12 running any version of iOS 14 is broken
2. USB tethering with an iPhone 12 running any version of iOS 14 is broken
3. Bluetooth tethering with an iPhone 12 *generally* works ... so long as you don't mind Bluetooth transmission speeds. Note:
   — Bluetooth 5.0 is 2Mbps
   — Bluetooth 4.2 is 1Mbps

Ubuntu 21.04 *should* see this update included in ipheth, and it will likely be back-ported to 20.04 LTS as well. There is little chance of seeing it in 16.04 LTS as that release is nearing EOL.

While this is not a great answer, I hope it gives you something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I can't hook up either Bluetooth or USB hotspot with my iPhone 12 and my System 76 laptop running Ubuntu 20.04LTS, which I upgraded from 18.04LTS. However, if I connect the phone to the laptop with the USB cable, enable Bluetooth on both devices and go to the network setting on the laptop, and select iPhone under the "other devices", I get online that way.

I don't know if this connection is a Bluetooth or USB connection, but I can stream Netflix with it, so it's usable. Otherwise, it's a full-service internet connection (email, browsing, Google search functions, etc). Seems to be a genuine hotspot to me. I don't have wifi.